# How can I get the physical specs about a GPU in D3D12

Tags: direct3d12

How can I get the physical specs (memory size, etc.) of a GPU in D3D12? (This would be useful to activate/deactivate some features for specific GPU specs)

Comment: Have you tried [IDXGIAdapter::GetDesc()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiadapter-getdesc?redirectedfrom=MSDN)?

Answer (score 0):

With DirectX 12, you do this through the `IDXGIAdapter3::QueryVideoMemoryInfo`.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/memory-management-strategies#memory-budget)

> As with most things in DirectX 12, memory management and dealing with VRAM over-commit is left as something the application has to explicitly deal with. Unlike with DirectX 11, it won't degrade gracefully by default. You should take a look at the Residency library sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12Residency).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [DXGI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59981128/986) is to use [DXCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_dxcore/), specifically `IDXCoreAdapter::QueryState` with `DXCoreAdapterState::AdapterMemoryBudget`. This will give you access to:

```
struct DXCoreAdapterMemoryBudget {
  uint64_t budget;
  uint64_t currentUsage;
  uint64_t availableForReservation;
  uint64_t currentReservation;
};
```